# Generate random number in range in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, random

I'm trying to get a random number generator working on the iPhone. There are two text fields a label and a button. Enter the minimum number in one textfield and the maximum in the next. Clicking the button will display the random number in the UILabel. I did this once before and can't figure it out for the life of me today. Any code or places I could visit to find this out would be fantastic.

Thanks

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
NSString *min = myMinTextField.text; //Get the current text from your minimum and maximum textfields.
NSString *max = myMaxTextField.text;

int randNum = rand() % ([max intValue] - [min intValue]) + [min intValue]; //create the random number.

NSString *num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", randNum]; //Make the number into a string.

[myLabel setText:num]; // Give your label the value of the string that contains the number.
```

Update:

It appears that it is probably better to use `arc4random` as opposed to `rand` you can see more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328950/c-the-definitive-truth-about-rand-random-and-arc4random). Just replace all the `rand`s with `arc4random`

Comment: I remember now! That was exactly how I did it. Thanks a million

Comment: I perfer `arc4random()` for generating random numbers.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I couldn't seem to get arc4random to work for me. Don't know why. Anyhow thanks so much

Comment: This code is working properly to generate random numbers between a range but it is not displaying last number. Means between range (1 to 50 ) it is showing numbers between 1 to 49.

Comment: @HimanshuMahajan: If you want the range to be inclusive: `([max intValue] - [min intValue]+1) + [min intValue]`

Comment: Or just rand() % ([max intValue] would be enough (no need of subtracting and adding the same variable)

Comment: @Gokul: Your reasoning is incorrect. Notice the parentheses. `rand() % ([max inValue] - [min intValue])` generates a range from 0 to the "distance" of max and min. Then you shift this upward by the minimum value.

Comment: I stand corrected :)

Comment: So glad this immediately closed question is so useful...  and still alive!  :-)  Thanks Dair (and for the recent clairifications)

Answer (score 24):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int randomNumber = min + rand() % (max-min);
```