# IOS Random Image in Image View when the view loads

Tags: ios, image, view, random

I'm trying to randomly display an image when my view loads. I don't want it to be from a UIButton, just whenever the view loads.

I've added the UIImage View to my View Controller http://bit.ly/1aopaMV and I've created a property for it.

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

I'm not sure how to add images to the UIImage View and do it randomly.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm a total noob.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of potential image names, determine a random number (like this: [Generate random number in range in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601953/generate-random-number-in-range-in-ios)), then set the `image` property of the `UIImageView`.

All this could be placed in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillDisplay:` methods of your view controller.

There are, of course other approaches, but this would be fairly simple.

Comment: I don't really understand how to do this.

Comment: basically what he is saying is have an array of known image names. When the view is about to appear on the screen, randomly generate a number which will indicate an index for the array of names. Once you have that index, retrieve the corresponding name, and now you have selected your random image.

Answer (score 0):

viewWillAppear:

```
NSArray *myImageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"img1.png", @"img2.png", @"img3.png", nil]; 
int randomNumber = arc4random() % [myImageArray count];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImageArray objectAtIndex:(randomNumber)]];
```

The assumptions here are that you have a static list of possible images and those images are locally stored within the project. This is a quick & dirty implementation of what you're asking to achieve. It also assumes you're using ARC.