# iAd intersitial loaded only once

Tags: ios, iad

I need to load an intersitial add randomly when a ViewController loads. In order to achieve this, I use this code:

```
self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyAutomatic;
```

The problem is that the intersitial is loaded once, and then, it is not shown any more.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy), `ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyAutomatic` means that:

> Automatic policy. **The framework determines when an interstitial ad is presented.**

(emphasis mine).

If you want it to be random, I think you need `ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual`, which allows you to control when an interstitial is shown:

> Manual policy. The app determines when an interstitial ad should be presented. Use `requestInterstitialAdPresentation` to request the presentation of an interstitial ad at an appropriate time.

So use `ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual`, and call `requestInterstitialAdPresentation` when you want an ad to be shown.

It's unclear what you mean by "*load an interstitial ad randomly*", but with the manual approach you can control when you want it presented. For example, you could use the approaches in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601953/generate-random-number-in-range-in-ios) to generate a number between 0 and 1, inclusive, and if it's 1 show the ad. Otherwise, don't show it.