# swift: how to remove randomly from 1 to 3 items?

Tags: swift, random, hidden, arc4random

My code remove randomly only one coin. How i can remove randomly from 1 to 3 coins?

```
@IBAction func endTurn(sender: UIButton!) {
    if coins.count > 0 { // @IBOutlet var coins: [UIButton]! (21 coins)
        let index: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(coins.count)))
        coins[index].hidden = true
        self.coins.removeAtIndex(index)
        if coins.isEmpty {
            println("GameOver")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do a random between 1 and 3 and a for loop calling your code?

Comment: Already answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601953/generate-random-number-in-range-in-ios
Note: use arc4random as opposed to rand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
let numberToDelete = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3))) + 1

for i in 0..<numberToDelete{
    let indexToDelete = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(coins.count)))
    coins.removeAtIndex(indexToDelete)
    if coins.isEmpty{
        break;
    }
}
if coins.isEmpty{
    println("GameOver")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For randoms I recommend this `extension`:

```
extension Int {
    static func random(range: Range<Int> ) -> Int {
        var offset = 0

        if range.startIndex < 0 {
            offset = abs(range.startIndex)
        }

        let min = UInt32(range.startIndex + offset)
        let max = UInt32(range.endIndex   + offset)

        return Int(min + arc4random_uniform(max - min)) - offset
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var i = Int.random(1...5)
```

Comment: This is very nice, congrats. But I think it should be `if range.startIndex < 0 {`