# Generating a random number under super.ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am making a 'Guess The Number' Game for a project at school, I want my application to generate one random number between 1-10 and then let me use it under my button which allows the user to guess the number by entering their guess into a text field. I have managed to do some of this, my random number generator is currently under my 'Guess' Button which means every time they press the button the number will change. My solution is to generate a number under super.viewDidLoad and then use it under the button to do the rest, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: I guess you mean  just 'viewDidLoad', except you've got a complex ViewController-structure with inheritance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601953/generate-random-number-in-range-in-ios?rq=1 Here is the Obj C version I think you can convert it to swift

Comment: He doesn't want to know how to generate numbers randomly, he wants to know when and how to initialize them.

Comment: Yes I know how to generate a random number, but I dont want it to generate under my button, I just want it to generate the number asoon as the program runs.

Comment: Just a comment here: when you create it only when loading your view, once the user guessed the number correctly he will have to restart your game. It'd be cleaner to move the logic into a seperate method which you can call in your viewDidLoad-method and also when the user guesses correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly you want the number to be generated only once instead of on every press.

So you might want something like this:

```
var randomNumber: Int

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Initialization
    generateRandomNumber()
}

func generateRandomNumber() {
    randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(9)) + 1
}
```

randomNumber is an instance-variable, so you can access it in all of your methods, for example to check if the user guessed correctly.

Comment: Yes you do understand me correctly thanks ill try it!

Comment: just a question. after "randomNumber =" do i put arc4random?

Comment: Yes or whatever you've already used to generate random numbers. From your question I read that the random-algorithm already works. Just move it from the "button-pressed" method to here.

Comment: Okay, I am using ' Double(arc4random() % 11)' but when I typed it in it says "Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'Int' "

Comment: Ah well Double is a different data-type than Int. Double are floating-point numbers, which dont make a lot of sense for a guessing-game as nobody wants to guess 4.5612. Int are only the natural numbers so 1, 2, 3, 4... and so on

Comment: Okay I get it now, so what should I do?

Comment: `arc4random_uniform(9)+1`   let me explain :) This is a bit cleaner than your modulo-method. arc4random_uniform(9) will produce a number from 0 to 9. And by adding 1 it will then fit your range from 1 to 10

Comment: This makes perfect sense, but now its telling me "Cannot convert value of UInt32 to expected argument type Int"

Comment: Check my answer again, I added it there. Haven't worked with Swift for some time :D What this does it creates a new Int-value with the UInt32-value returned from the random-method because UInt32 can't be casted to Int directly

Comment: You're welcome. I've changed my answer a bit, I moved the logic into a method so you can call it also when the user guessed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but Its okay, I have already made a algorithm that checks if the answer is correct. Thanks anyway. I hope you dont mind that if  I have any other minor questions could I just ask you?

Comment: Going to be difficult as SO doesn't have a PM system. You can try posting it here as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard library functions for high quality random numbers: `arc4random()` or `arc4random_uniform()`, just as in Objective-C.

They are in the Darwin module, so you will need to `import Darwin` if you haven't imported AppKit, UIKit, or Foundation.

Comment: Thanks but im a little bit confused about the import Darwin part?

Comment: if you haven't imported AppKit, UIKit, or Foundation. then only u have to import drawin

Comment: I may sound stupid haha but I am not sure how to do that.